OpenSSL: error:0A00010B:SSL routines::wrong version number (TortoiseGit - Git SCM)
I want to use TortoiseGit to push a software revision from my local domain to a remote server hosted on GitHub.
To push the software to the remote server, right-click on the local directory and follow the steps below:

But both the command line tool and the TortoiseGit client return the following error.

How can I fix this issue?

Does your network require a proxy for HTTPS?

Looks like you may be trying to connect an HTTPS client to an HTTP server.

@JimRedmond I don't need such a thing

@AndrewHenle Yo, my man! This detail must be a joke! Because the feature that didn't work yesterday worked today! I didn't change anything! What could have changed? Dadgum!
